# Jquery`s "includedContent" + SEO =?

Tags: jquery, seo

**I base my homepage on Jquery`s "includedContent".**

Most of the content in index.html looks like this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#includedContentNavbar").load("/navbar.html");
        $("#includedContentmain").load("/main.html");
        $("#includedContent").load("/content.html");
        $("#includedContentGallery").load("/gallery.html");
        $("#includedContentfooter").load("/footer.html");
        $("#includedContentModal").load("/modal.html");

    });
</script>

<body>

    <div id="page-top"></div> 
    <div id="includedContentNavbar"></div>
    <div id="includedContentModal"></div>
    <div id="includedContentmain"></div>
    <div id="includedProjectContent"></div>
    <div id="includedContentGallery"></div>
    <div id="includedContentfooter"></div>


    <!-- Core JavaScript Files -->
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>


</body>
```

So all the real content is placed on different html pages for reuse, and called in with "includeContent".

Question is, when google crawl my website, and there are no real links to my sub pages, does google find all the keywords/text on my sub pages?

I build this this way so i only have to edit stuff in one document(eks.:navbar.html) and have much less code. But can someone tell me whats the correct/a better way of building up a website with multiple sub pages, footer,navbar, etc...?

website: [www.pb-studios.com](http://www.pb-studios.com)

Comment: short answer is no, google won't find your content but they do have a set of guidlines for ajax driven sites and they can be made SEO friendly but you will need to provide server side html snapshots and set up page and links per their spec

Comment: ok, thanx, so i guess i follow this one: [https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=en].


I build this this way so i only have to edit stuff in one document(eks.:navbar.html) and have much less code. But can someone tell me whats the correct/a better way of building up a website with multiple sub pages, footer,navbar, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

For SEO best practice, if you can "view source" in a web browser and find actual words that an average human can read, there's a good bet that Google, Yahoo/Bing and other search engines can also read it.  If you look at your source code, and all you see are java[script] calls, then there's very little if any keyword/content relevance to your site.

If you want to see exactly what Google "sees" in the way of content, you will want to sign up for a Google webmaster account (www.google.com/webmaster) and click "Crawl" then "Fetch as Google."  Here you can specify any page within your site, and Google will show you exactly what it "sees" on that page.  If you're not seeing the keywords you want the page to rank for, there's a really good chance that you won't rank for it.